# Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027fff\u0027.","StackTrace

Tags: asp.net

i have a js file.a want to pass a value as a json using ajax to my codebehind but i get this error:
Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027fff\u0027.","StackTrace

my javascript code is:

```
var values = { fff: "tttttttt" };
var uname = "fariddddddd";
  $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "http://localhost:39787/Default.aspx/dataSave",
 data: JSON.stringify(values),
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 processData: false,
 success: function (msg) {
     AjaxSucceeded(msg);
 },
 error: function (msg) {
     alert(msg);
 }
     });
```

my code behind is:

```
[WebMethod(true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string dataSave(string fff)  
 {
   string a = fff + "kazemi";
   return a;
```

}

please help me

Answer (score 1):

you are not enclosing the Key with quotes. change the declaration to like this. read this [UnQuoted Object in javascript](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties)

```
var values = { "fff": "tttttttt" };
```